# Process the next line based on previous line in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data from a log file, which looks something like below:

> messageprolog  =[version .....]

```
0:  |....h..|

16: |.....ho|

32: |wareyou|
```

payload contents:

```
0:  |...abc..|

16: |.....iam|

32: |good....|

64: |...hbu..|
```

DEBUG request provider

I want to process this file and as output i want to combine the data enclosed in pipes ||. One set of data in pipes should be output as one line and another line from other set.

Like the above should output below:

```
....h.......howareyou

...abc.......iamgood.......hbu..
```

I am looking as to how it can be done in spark, with benefits of parallel processing as the size of log is large?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of the file you are parsing?

Comment: There is no recognizable pattern in the file to distribute each part of the data within pipes in a separate partition. Won't be able to put up the exact data from the file due to legal reasons.